# Where does this autocomplete feature come from?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

[image: Demonstration of autocomplete popup in vscode integrated terminal]

Have been searching with no avail about the autocomplete feature seen in screenshot above, which seems to suddenly appear around half year ago or so. It provides auto-completion for powershell cmdlets and certain other external commands (such as `git`), and only appear from within vscode integrated terminal where powershell is used (no such feature for `cmd.exe` or other shells).

For me the most important question is, how can it be permanently disabled? It was causing much pain and disruption when using the integrated terminal, such as double typing of each and every character, or outright permanent terminal deadlock (need to kill and restart).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not searching harder, as I have found the culprit soon afterwards: `terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.suggestEnabled`. And indeed some people are also [having issues](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/206172) as I do. On the other hand, why this feature doesn't appear earlier in my working env is beyond me.